# PHP SQL Trigger

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I write a simple trigger in php, here is my code

```
$triggerQuery = 
"DELIMITER  && 
create or replace Trigger insert_room_type after insert on hotel for each row
begin 
insert into room_type values(NEW.hotelID,'Single',0,NULL);
insert into room_type values(NEW.hotelID,'Double',0,NULL);
insert into room_type values(NEW.hotelID,'Standard',0,NULL);
insert into room_type values(NEW.hotelID,'Superior',0,NULL);
end && DELIMITER ;";
```

However, when the code runs, only the first insertion (out of 4) was perform, Can anyone told me what I did wrong?? Thx in advance.

by the way, the primary key for room_type is hotelID & RoomCategory(which is the second column) so there souldn't be any primary key violation right?

Comment: you don't need to create a trigger every time. It must be created only once.

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of triggers being created with PHP. Also they are created only once!

To fix your error you have to change the delimiter. Otherwise MySQL thinks that the trigger is finished with the first `;`.

```
DELIMITER $$
create Trigger insert_room_type after insert on hotel for each row
begin 
insert into room_type values(NEW.hotelID,'Single',0,NULL);
insert into room_type values(NEW.hotelID,'Double',0,NULL);
insert into room_type values(NEW.hotelID,'Standard',0,NULL);
insert into room_type values(NEW.hotelID,'Superior',0,NULL); 
end $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thx man, I add in the delimiter but still the same result, is it because the mysql_query doesn't work with this， here is how I execute it
    $trigger = mysql_query($triggerQuery,$con);

Comment: I have no clue about PHP, but I know of limitations like only one statement and so on. Please just execute what I posted above directly on the database. Really, it also doesn't make sense to use PHP here.

Comment: And if there are still errors then, please post exact error message.